# Двумерный массив в Python

Tags: python, массивы

Только начинаю вникать в python, хотел написать простенький консольный платформер, по типу "увернись от предмета и лети дальше". Проблемы начались уже при отрисовке игрового поля. Код:

```
import time

def clear():
    arr = []
    line = ["."]*29
    line.append("#")
    for i in range(5):
        arr.append(line)
    return arr

game_range = []
sharps_index = [[30,1]*6]
k = 29
game_range = clear()

for j in range(10):
    print("\n" * 50)
    game_range = clear()

    game_range[2][k] = "#"

    k = k-1

    for i in range(5):
        print(''.join(game_range[i]))

    time.sleep(1)
```

Вопрос - почему при вызове `game_range[2][k] = "#"` заменяется целый столбец значений, и получается не одиноко летящий "астероид", а надвигающаяся стена:

```
......................#......#
......................#......#
......................#......#
......................#......#
......................#......#

.....................#.......#
.....................#.......#
.....................#.......#
.....................#.......#
.....................#.......#
```

и так далее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что переменная `line` указывает на объект "список" в памяти и при добавлении этой переменной в массив `arr` происходит добавление указателя.

В итоге получается список из пяти указателей на один и тот же список. При попытке изменения элемента в этом списке списков фактически изменяется значение в исходном списке `line`. Список списков состоит из пяти таких элементов, соответственно изменённое значение будет находиться во всех элементах.

[image: Один объект в нескольких списках]