# Формирование списка в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Почему `['d']` на первом месте в списке `x` и почему повторяется `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

```py
x = [[]]*3

x[0].append('a')
x[1].append('b')
x[2].append('c')
x[0]=['d']

print(x)
```

*stdout:*

```py
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: вы правы)) я случайно нажал "опубликовать"

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Двумерный массив в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/945018/204271)

Comment: Исправить: `x = [[] for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если выражаться просто, то список - это некое хранилище ссылок.

В Вашем примере, при умножении, новые списки не создаются. Вы размножаете ссылки.
Поэтому после первой инструкции список содержит 3 ссылки на один и тот же объект списка.

Проверить это можно с помощью оператора `is`:

```py
x = [[]] * 3
print(x[0] is x[1] is x[2])  # True
```

Вот и получается, что Вы добавляете элементы в одни и те же списки:

*stdout:*

```py
[['d'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

`['d']` оказался на первом месте, так как Вы явно создали новый объект с помощью литералов и заменили ссылку в `x[0]`